# Google Earth Pro Returns Unknown Graphics Card And Will Not Launch 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-earth

I have downloaded Google Earth Pro 7.3.3 deb file and installed the software.  On execution I get an error message that the graphics card is not recognized.  I did uninstall an earlier (unknown) version of Google Earth Pro that was working fine.  Why will this newer version Google Earth not execute without error?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing happen when some virtual memory allocations are too limited for the applications that are being run. Can you update your question to include the output of `cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i vmalloc` ?

Comment: Also, how did you install the Video driver?  I am running 455.45.01 installed from the `graphics-drivers` PPA and Google Earth Pro 7.3.3 works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

After restarting the computer Google Earth 7.3.3 is working correctly.

Comment: Confirming this worked for me as well, thank you for saving me a bunch of time.